# Magento 2 - AddAttributeToSelect("customattr") only returns products where customattr is not null

Tags: magento2, collection

I have added an extra sort by option to my magento 2 store which uses the price divided by a **unit_of_sale** attribute to sort the catalog by an each price.

The sort works in a lot of categories from what i can tell however some show no or less products when sorted by this option:

**Code for the collection below:**

```
case 'each_price':
                if ( $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc' ) {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('unit_of_sale', 'catalog_product_entity_varchar')            
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('price_index.min_price / IF(unit_of_sale = NULL, 1, unit_of_sale) DESC'));
                } elseif ( $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc' ) {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('unit_of_sale', 'catalog_product_entity_varchar')                            
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('price_index.min_price / IF(unit_of_sale = NULL, 1, unit_of_sale) ASC'));
                }
                break;
```

**UPDATE**

Products that have no **unit_of_sale** set set are removed from the collection. How can i add the attribute so that I can run this simple calculation for sort but without removing items where **unit_of_sale** are null?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  expression from

```
IF(unit_of_sale = NULL, 1, unit_of_sale)
```

to

```
IFNULL(unit_of_sale,1)
```

because in MySQL NULL != NULL

Comment: Thanks for that still seems to be behaving the same way tho with some categories just showing no products with this sort. Categories that work do show products with unit of sale null have done in both cases so that's why i'm confused.

Comment: I think my problem is the null thing. It's just this doesn't seem to fix it for some reason. If they are null they just aren't included in the collection.